# multithreaded TCP server in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, tcpsocket

I need a TCP server to do the following things:

1. Always listen for connection requests, even after a connection has been established.
2. When a new connection request is waiting, close the existing connection, and accept the new one.

I tried to use threads to handle connections. The main thread accepts the request, and spawns individual thread for each request.

```
auto connectionHandler = [](someParams)
{
    while (true)
    {
        recv();
    }
}

while (true)
{
    if ((mClientFd = accept(mServerFd, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddress,
            &clientLength)) < 0)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        std::thread(connectionHandler, someParams);
        if joinable() join();
    }
}
```

I don't know how to check if any previous connectionHandler thread is still running, and I don't know how to terminate that running thread without affecting the main thread.

Comment: Unrelated: This might be the result of over-reducing the problem, but creating a thread followed by immediately `join`ing the thread effectively makes your code serial. The thread is useless.

Comment: Terminating a thread is usually a bad idea. It can leave a program in an undefined state. Loop on an atomic flag in `connectionHandler ` and time out the call to the `recv` (I usually do this with `select` and then `recv` if there is data). When a new connection comes in, set the flag, and when the `recv` times out the loop will exit, `connectionHandler` will return, and the thread will die a clean death..In some systems you may be able to eliminate the time-out and close the socket to get out of the `recv`.

Comment: BTW, this isn't really much different from a 'process per connection' model and will not really be any faster than it (except on Windows, where it will be tons faster).

Comment: @user4581301 - Well, there is a test to see if it is joinable first. And this is also clearly a pseudocode sketch. So I don't imagine the OP intends to do that particular stupid thing.

Comment: I hope not, but it does crop up from time to time, so I figure better safe than sorry.

Comment: My bad, I used thread::operator= in my program, so I had to check if it's joinable. Otherwise, std::terminate() is called.

Comment: I guess I'll put the handler on a separate process, and send kill signal to terminate it. Thanks guys.

Comment: No, there is a better way. It's just a pain to answer this question because it's a bunch of code. Basically you have to use semaphores and timeouts to signal the various threads. It is doable. But unless you have a compelling reason to share memory there is no really good reason to use threads over processes. Personally, I'd use an `epoll` based event loop without any threads or processes on Linux. Or use an Open Source library called _libevent_ that would let you have a cross-platform way to do the same thing.

Comment: @ljulyl Why not look at code that does this, which is pretty much every multithreaded server that handles TCP connections, and see how others do it. There's lots of frameworks and libraries to help you do this. Boost, for example, has fantastic asynchronous multi-threaded I/O that fits C++ coding patterns extremely well by design.

Comment: I’ll try epoll/select with non blocking today, so I don’t have to handle the termination of threads. Hopefully it works. Thanks a lot guys. Really appreciated!